# Ada derived types and primitive operation

Tags: ada

I have the following Ada Code.

```
type U i s tagged private ;
type W i s new U with private ;
type X i s new W with private ;

procedure m1 (P1 : U; P2 : in out U; P3 : Integer ) ;
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out U) ;
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : Boolean ; P3 : in out W) ;
```

Not I dont understand what happens excatly with this operations in the derived types.
I think the 3 procedures are primitive operations.

But what is the signature of the procedures in the derived types.

Could it be this

```
procedure m1 (P1 : W; P2 : in out U; P3 : Integer ) ;
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out W) ;
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : Boolean ; P3 : in out X) ;
```

Or what would the signature looks like of these 3 procedures in derived types?

Answer (score 3):

When a type T has a primitive subprogram, and you say "type T2 is new T" or "type T2 is new T with ...", a new subprogram is implicitly declared.  In the new subprogram, if any parameter type is `T` or `access T`, it's replaced by `T2` or `access T2`; and if it's a function whose return type is `T` or `access T`, the return type is replaced similarly.

If there were no `private` types or extensions involved, the new subprogram would be implicitly declared right after the derived type.  E.g.:

```
type U is tagged null record ;
procedure m1 (P1 : U; P2 : in out U; P3 : Integer ) ;
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out U) ;

type W is new U with null record ;
-- procedure m1 (P1 : W; P2 : in out W; P3 : Integer ) ; --implicitly declared
-- procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out W) ; --implicitly declared
procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : Boolean ; P3 : in out W);
    -- this last is a *new* procedure.  It doesn't override the other m2 because
    -- it has a new Boolean parameter.  Instead, it's an example of *overloading*.

-- So now W has three primitive operations, two that were inherited and one that
-- is brand new.

type X is new W with null record ;
-- procedure m1 (P1 : X; P2 : in out X; P3 : Integer ) ; --implicitly declared
-- procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out X) ; --implicitly declared
-- procedure m2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : Boolean ; P3 : in out X); --implicitly declared

-- All three of W's primitive operations, including the implicitly declared ones,
-- are inherited for X.
```

The `with private` doesn't change things much, except that it changes the point where the implicit subprograms are declared.  I believe they're declared after the **full** type definition, which would be in the private part of your package.  That means that they aren't visible except in places in your program that can see the private part of your package.  (However, they might still be called by a dispatching operation.)

**EDIT:** For a `with private` case, the visibility of the inherited subprograms is dictated by [RM 7.3.1(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-7-3-1.html):

> For a private_extension_declaration, each inherited subprogram is declared immediately after the private_extension_declaration if the corresponding declaration from the ancestor is visible at that place. Otherwise, the inherited subprogram is not declared for the private extension, though it might be for the full type.

Thus:

```
package P is

    type U is tagged private;
    procedure M1 (P1 : U; P2 : in out U; P3 : Integer);
    procedure M2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out U);

    type W is new U with private;
    --procedure M1 (P1 : W; P2 : in out W; P3 : Integer); -- implicitly declared
    --procedure M2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out W); -- implicitly declared

private
    type U is ... -- full type definition
    type W is new U with ...  -- full type definition
end P;
```

The declarations of `M1` and `M2` are visible at the point where `W` is first declared; thus they're inherited at that point.  And since that point is in the public part of P, they can be referenced by any package that says `with P`.  But:

```
package P is

    type U is tagged private;

    type W is new U with private;

    procedure M1 (P1 : U; P2 : in out U; P3 : Integer);
    procedure M2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out U);

private
    type U is ... -- full type definition
    type W is new U with ...  -- full type definition
    --procedure M1 (P1 : W; P2 : in out W; P3 : Integer); -- implicitly declared
    --procedure M2 (P1 : Float ; P2 : in out W); -- implicitly declared
end P;
```

The declarations of `M1` and `M2` are *not* visible at the point where `W` is first declared, since they haven't been seen yet.  Thus they're *not* inherited at that point.  But the implicit declarations are inherited later, when the full type is seen.  However, those implicit declarations are in the `private` part of `P`; therefore, they can be called directly (i.e. not via dispatching) only in parts of the program that can see the `private` part of `P`, i.e. `P`'s body and at appropriate places in child packages of `P`.